# PIXI js canvas pixels are saved as black for some reason

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

So I was trying to extract the pixels from my PIXI.js canvas, and I inspected them, and while the canvas on the screen had an image on it, the pixels extracted were completely black...

So then I investagated, and here is what I found (i need help)

Background info:

setup:

```
this.canvas = $('#canvas');
this.canvasDOM = this.canvas[0];

this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(0, 0, {
  view: this.canvasDOM,
  resolution: 1
});
```

Getting Image:

```
chooseImage(src) {
  const self = this;

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = src;

  image.onload = function() {
    const base = new PIXI.BaseTexture(image);
    const texture = new PIXI.Texture(base);
    const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

    sprite.position.set(0, 0);
    self.currentImage = sprite;

    self.render();
  };
}
```

rendering image:

```
render() {
  if (this.currentImage) {
    this.updateDimensions();

    const stage = new PIXI.Container();
    stage.addChild(this.currentImage);
    stage.filters = this.gatherFilters();

    const { width, height } = this.currentImage;
    stage.filterArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

    this.renderer.render(stage);
  }
}
```

ok, so you can ignore the code which is before the rendering function, but in particular, the third last line of the rendering function is:

```
this.renderer.render(stage);
```

Now, this works perfectly fine! the image pops up and is a bright jellyfish on the canvas, but there is one small issue:

If i add this to the end of the render() function:

```
render() {
  if (this.currentImage) {
    this.updateDimensions();

    const stage = new PIXI.Container();
    stage.addChild(this.currentImage);
    stage.filters = this.gatherFilters();

    const { width, height } = this.currentImage;
    stage.filterArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

    this.renderer.render(stage);

    const actualCanvas = this.renderer.extract.canvas; // the actual canvas on the screen

    console.log(actualCanvas.toDataURL());
  }
}
```

It returns a long string, and if replace

```
console.log(actualCanvas.toDataURL());
```

with: (the download lib)

```
download(actualCanvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'image.png', 'image/png');
```

It downloads the jellyfish image!

now, in another function, I was going to have the image downloaded as either a png or jpg (and the array of possible download types was in another class and decided dynamically, so I couldn't simply cache the pixels after rendering)

to show u my issue, I will change the above code to:

```
setTimeout(() => download(actualCanvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'image.png', 'image/png'), 1 /* One second delay */);
```

now the image is blank; black., unlike before when it worked

the only thing that changed was the delay I added.

I further inspected this, and i realised that if i did

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(this.renderer.extract.pixels()), 1); // extract the pixels after some delay for testing
```

then they were all black, but if i removed the delay, it worked again

again, in my case, I can't simply cache the image for my own reasons (don't ask)

So i was wandering if there was a workaround so that after some delay or later on the pixels when I extract them are not just black and work like it does without the delay.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your timeout code is 1 millisecond and not 1 second. so the download didn't finish yet. put 1000 instead of 1 in the timeout or maybe  5000 just for test

Comment: I know i tested 1000 and 5000 and all that, the problem is that if there is a delay, ie. the image is saved or the canvas pixels are extracted at *any* time after rendering, they will return a bunch of blackness, even if the canvas on screen shows a complete picture

Answer (score 0):

It seems some kind of browser protection to me. Maybe non-event-driven code protection accessing some resources or maybe non-https webapps protection (did you tried your app thru https even without certificate?), or maybe it can be even some kind of crossdomain protection (I doubt about it, but always present in the to-check list). Maybe you can deploy a fiddle or similar to test. Hope it helps!